# How can I re-populate a ListBox without causing InvalidOperation exception due to invalid SelectedItem?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a set of ObservableCollections which is being used amongst other things to present choices to the user in the form of ListBoxes. These are populated based on XML data from a server when the user logs in.

In the UI, these collections are bound to e.g. a ListBox;

```
public constructor() {
    listBox.ItemsSource = App.Current.myCollection;
```

When logging out, the user is brought back to the first page (I forward to the login page, and remove all back entries in OnNavigatedTo).

And here is the problem: When relogging, it seems difficult to repopulate the collections in a sane way that allows the listboxes to have a transient state (which it does when you first log in).

The other surprising discovery here is that even when a page has not been navigated to, ListBoxes bound to my collections do change selection when manually clearing and repopulating the collection.

Any ideas for a more elegant approach?

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your code? It is hard to know exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out lack of code, extracting a minimal sample actually solved it for me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit; when setting up the data binding in the constructor, changes to the collection can be applied prematurely. The right approach is to assign the ItemsSource in Loaded or OnNavigated